# Using Hash Maps to represent an extremely large data source

Tags: c++, stl, hashmap, hash

I have a very large possible data set that I am trying to visualize at once. The set itself consists of hundreds of thousands of segments, each of which is mapped to an id.

I have received a second data source that gives more real-time information for each segment, but the id's do not correspond to the id's I have.

I have a 1:1 mapping of the data id's (9-character strings) to the current id's (long integers). The problem is that there are a lot of id's, and the data that is coming in is in no specific order.

The solution I came up with is to have a hash-map that maps the strings to the road id's. The problem is that I don't know if the hash-map will be efficient enough to have all 166k data entries.

Does anyone have any suggestions and/or hashing algorithms that I can use for this?

Comment: What does "efficient enough" mean? Fast enough? In which case what speeds on what hardware? Or space efficient enough? In which case what storage have you got? Basically, your question as it stands cannot be answered sensibly.

Comment: Another idea would be to (offline) transform one of the data sets to use the same id as the other before you load it into your visualization application.

Comment: The hashes will be used about 160k times per cycle, and I would like to have each cycle to be on the order of a minute. The hardware is a typical machine found today - maybe 2GB ram, 4GhZ processor.

The program currently takes up around 400MB of space when running. I obviously don't want to use more than 10% more of that for this structure.

Comment: @lothar: A different data source uses the original data, so we can't remove the original set. We also don't have the ability to edit the original data set, and it is loaded as it is needed, not all at once - so we can't just edit the offline data itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only dealing with hundreds of thousands of datapoints, it will likely not be a problem to go with the naive way and just stick with a hash-map.

Even if you have 500,000 9-character strings and an equal number of `long`s, that still only 16ish bytes per item, or 8,000,000 bytes total.  Even if you double that for overhead, 16 MB is hardly too big to have in memory at one time.

Basically, try the easy way first, and only worry about it when your profiling tells you it's taking too long.

Answer (score 1):

[Judy Arrays](http://judy.sourceforge.net/) are designed for this sort of thing: "Judy's key benefits are scalability, high performance, and memory efficiency. [...] Judy can replace many common data structures, such as arrays, sparse arrays, hash tables, B-trees, binary trees, linear lists, skiplists, other sort and search algorithms, and counting functions."

Comment: I read the site, and it seems like bad marketing hype. Is it really as good as they say, and if so, why haven't more people heard of them?

Comment: I honestly don't know.  I did try out the library a while ago and it seemed to work as advertised, but I didn't do any serious benchmarking and I haven't used it in production code.

Comment: Its not marketing. For that you should hire sun or microsoft. Most people don't solve problems where it matters (they are using a RDBMS, so everyhing else is fast enough). The implementation combines badly with OO and VM implementations, and is heavily architecture dependent.

Comment: @Stephan so you are saying that judy is heavily architecture dependent?

Answer (score 1):

Since the comments on the question indicate the primary concern may be memory usage:

- Use a **pooling or other small-object-optimized allocator**; assuming you have access to [boost](http://www.boost.org/) you can probably find a drop-in replacement in [Pool](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/pool/doc/index.html).  Using a better small-object allocator is probably the single biggest memory win you'll find.
- If you know your strings are fixed-width, you may want to make sure you're **allocating only enough space** to store them.  For example, a struct wrapped around a fixed-length char[] with a custom comparison operator may work better than a std::string.  std::string comes with an additional dynamic allocation (and uses space for the corresponding pointer) and some extra size and capacity tracking overhead.  (Generally, try to **reduce the number of allocations** that stick around; it reduces overhead.)
- (Assuming STL) Look at the overhead difference between std::map and std::unordered_map (the latter may or may not be available to you at the moment); an **RBtree-based std::map** may be close enough to the lookup performance characteristics of your "hashmap" and may (or may not) be more memory efficient depending on your standard library implementation.

What route you take should be influenced by info you can gather -- try to get a picture of number of allocs and alloc size/alignment overhead.

You can either instrument your allocator or insert a few elements and see how you're doing compared to how you think you should be doing in terms of memory usage.

Comment: Incidentally, reduction in memory usage often gives a good speed boost too.

Answer (score 0):

Since your strings are known up front and have a fixed length, theoretically and practically the best solution is a *perfect* hash. You could use [cmph](http://cmph.sourceforge.net/index.html) to generate it.

According to Wikipedia, your keys woud take 2.5 bits/key, or about 50KB. That's negligable compared to the 664KB for the values.

Answer (score 0):

Although 166k data entries is rather small IMO you can have a look at [google-sparsehash](http://code.google.com/p/google-sparsehash/)